# Enumerating three variables in python list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to print all the possible enumerations of a list for three variables. For example if my input is:

```
x = 1
y = 1
z = 1
```

I want the output to be like:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

If any of the x,y,z variables are higher than 1, it would enumerate all the integers from 0 to the variable value. For example, if x=3 then 0, 1, 2, or 3 would be possible in the first slot of the 3-element lists.

Right now I am creating the list comprehension like this:

```
output = [ [x,y,z] for x,y,z in range(x,y,z)]
```

I think something is wrong with the range function?

Comment: Do you want the output in exactly that order? And if so, how would be the order for more complex input?

Comment: I'm not that concerned with order, but would like it to be extensible to non-binary variable values, so like if x=2, there would be lists such as [2,0,0] [2,0,1], [2,1,0], [2,1,1] in the output as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Complementary to the solutions using `product`, you could also use a triple list comprehension.

```
>>> x, y, z = 1, 2, 3
>>> [(a, b, c) for a in range(x+1) for b in range(y+1) for c in range(z+1)]
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 2),
 (some more),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (1, 2, 3)]
```

The `+1` is necessary since `range` does not include the upper bound. 
If you want the output to be a list of lists, you can just do `[[a, b, c] for ...]`.

Note, however, that this will obviously only work is you always have three variables (`x`, `y`, `z`), while `product` would work with an arbitrary number of lists/upper limits.

Answer (score 15):

You could use the `product()` function from `itertools` as follows:

```
from itertools import product

answer = list(list(x) for x in product([0, 1], repeat=3))
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Actually, would like the variables possibly be not binary as well, so if x=2, y=1, z=1, there could be lists like [2,1,1] in the output as well... is there a way to do your solution using the x, y, and z variables rather than hard coding 1, and 0 there?

Comment: Happy to help, but probably best if you put it in a separate question, as it probably requires a slightly different approach!

Comment: Why convert afterwards? Just do the same before converting the `product` generator to a list, e.g. `[list(x) for x in product(...)]` or `list(map(list, product(...))`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `range()` function within a list comprehension and `itertools.product` function:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 1
>>> z = 1
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(*[range(i+1) for i in [x,y,z]]))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

This approach will work for different numbers too:

```
>>> x = 2
>>> y = 2
>>> z = 2
>>> 
>>> list(product(*[range(i+1) for i in [x,y,z]]))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
>>>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the output in the form of lists rather than tuples?

Comment: @WilliamRoss Yep you can use a list comprehension instead of `list` function. `[list(item) for item in product(*[range(i+1) for i in [x,y,z]])]`

Answer (score 4):

If you need it in form of a list of lists (instead of list of tuples) you can use `map` over the output of the answer by Kasramvd, that is:

```
map(list,list(product(*[range(i+1) for i in [x,y,z]])))
```

Comment: 1) in Python 3, `map` produces a generator, not a list, and 2) no need to turn the generator returned by `product` into a list before passing it to `map`. So this should rather be `list(map(list, product(...))`